# UIPath; execute simple powershell command: "(Get-PrintJob -PrinterName '015-pr362318-esr').count()"

Tags: powershell, uipath

I want to execute the following simple powershell command from within UIPath:

```
(Get-PrintJob -PrinterName '015-pr362318-esr').count()
```

and retrieve the output from within UIpath.

In order to execute the powershell command, I am currently using the invoke Power Shell activity from UIPath.

I tried already the following:

1. calling the command directly from within the above activity. Result: Error message: The term .... is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,....
2. calling just "get-printjob". from within the above activity. Result: Error message: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance' to type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject'

**Hint:** I have given the parameter -PrinterName via the parameter section of the invoke power shell activity.

**Edit:** This shows that the command: get-printjob is now recognized - but the resulting collection is of type ...CimInstance which cannot be cast to ...PSObject

**Question**: How can I use the get-printjob Powershell command within UIpath?

---

**Update - Solution (thanks to Mathias R. Jensen)**

**1st**
The checkbox "is script" must be checked. This will recognize the following line: "Import-Module PrintManagement; @(Get-PrintJob -PrinterName '015-pr362318-esr').Count" within UIPath's invoke power shell activity.

**2nd**
In order to extract the int32 value of the printjob count, put TypeArgument in the activity to: Int32

**3rd**
Define the UIPath variable `<yourReturnVariable>` which you assign within Output in the UIpath activity as follows: `Collection<Int32>`

**4th**
With an assign activity (after the invoke Power Shell activity), extract the number of print jobs as follows: `int_Printjobs = <yourReturnVariable>.First()`

Comment: Sounds like you want `Import-Module PrintManagement; @(Get-PrintJob -PrinterName '015-pr362318-esr').Count`

Comment: Hmm - no - this does also throw: "..." is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...

Comment: Does it literally say `...` or are you masking the real name of the command it can't resolve?

Comment: I have shorten the standard powershell feedback when it does not recognize a command for brevity here. I think the whole problem is very UIPath-specific and is not a powershell problem. If I execute the command on the UIpath robot server, it works in PWSH 5.1 as well as in PWSH 7.2.3. But as I have stated: I need to execute this powershell command in an UIpath workflow (in order to wait until the print queue is empty before the robot is allowed to continue).

Comment: Yeah, but I still have no idea _what_ it's not recognizing. Please just post the error message text _in full_.

Comment: Here we go - Full error message: Invoke Power Shell: The term 'Import-Module PrintManagement; @(Get-PrintJob -PrinterName '015-pr362318-esr').Count' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Aha! So it's interpreting _the whole script text_ as a single command name! That's very useful debugging info :) Perhaps you need to toggle [the `IsScript` parameter](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/invoke-power-shell#misc) of your "Invoke PowerShell" thing/element (I'm not sure what things are called in UiPath)

Comment: Mathias, thanks :-) - that was it basically. How could I oversee this checkbox there... And then it accepts the original powershell command as is. After that it is only a question of retreiving the correct type (collection of int32) and take the 1st element within the collection. If you put your comment as a full answer, I will gladly mark it as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full error message gives a hint:

> ```
> The term 'Import-Module PrintManagement; @(Get-PrintJob -PrinterName '015-pr362318-esr').Count' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> ```

So it's interpreting *the entire script* as the name of a single command to invoke - which obviously fails!

This might make very little sense if you're used to working with PowerShell interactively as a console application, how would you even attempt to invoke a command named like that?! (Hint: `&`)

But if you're working with the underlying API (like `UiPath` is), it's actually pretty *easy*:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("<# whole script text goes here#>");
// should have been `ps.AddScript("<# ... #>")`
```

The C# compiler happily compiles and executes this code, only you'll find at *runtime* that an error like the one you encounter.

So we need some way to instruct UiPath to call `AddScript()` instead of `AddCommand()`. According [to the UiPath docs](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/invoke-power-shell), the InvokePowerShell command element has an `IsScript` setting - my guess is that if you toggle it, it'll work! :)